# windows xp file searching help

Tags: windows-xp

I have a cad folder with a thousand file in it. say I want to open the 500th file, i scroll through 3 or 4 pages and open the file. then i want to open the 505th file. windows will take me back to the beginning page rather than start me out at the 500th file. i know it can do it because the cad guy next to me his computer does it. this is a real stumper and 5 experts anyready don't know help

Comment: 500th file sorted by what? creation time? alphabetical?

Comment: You'll have to make this more clear, as I can't reproduce this behavior... why should the file explorer take you back to the home position? When you open a file, it just opens another program, and the explorer stays in the same position.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following key combination:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⟵</kbd>

This will return your cursor to the folder you just opened in the parent directory and allow you to continue moving along the folders instead of being sent back to the start.